# How to create a re-usable caching method while using node-cache

Tags: node.js, caching

I'm using `node-cache` on my Node.JS & Express web service. But after a while, I've got a bunch of similar logics cluttering, like these:

```
let data = this.cache.get('some-key')
if (data) {
    return shopInfo
} else {
    data = someModel.find(id)
    this.cache.set('some-key', data)
    return data
}
```

I Googled about it and found a possible solution [here](https://medium.com/@danielsternlicht/caching-like-a-boss-in-nodejs-9bccbbc71b9b). But I don't wanna pass a callback function every time. Is there a better way? Or how can I modify it to utilize async/await instead of callback function?

```
get(key, storeFunction) {
    const value = this.cache.get(key);
    if (value) {
      return Promise.resolve(value);
    }

    return storeFunction().then((result) => {
      this.cache.set(key, result);
      return result;
    });
}
```

Comment: Do `someModel`, `'some-key'` and `id` all change in different examples of this logic? Is `'some-key'` equal to, related to or completely independent of `id`? Do you always need to call `find(id)` on a model to find the data if it hasn't already been cached? It's a little hard to tell what you actually need from your question.

Comment: If the answer is "No" will it be accepted? I can elaborate on your options, but basically one simple can not parameterize without passing parameters. You can switch to async/await, but without callbacks cluttering will remain.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a callback or promise as a parameter. Here's perhaps an easier way:

Helper function:

```
get(key, retrieveData) {
    const value = this.cache.get(key);
    if (value) {
      return value;
    }

    const data = retrieveData()
    this.cache.set(key, data);
    return data;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
const result = get('some-key', () => someModel.find(id))
return result
```

Despite using a callback, it's still clean. No need to complicate your code with promises if you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to past callback every time, you can do opposite - modify callback itself.

```js
// simple memoized...
function memoized(cache, fn) {
  return async key => cache.has(key) ? cache.get(key) : cache.set(key, await fn(key)).get(key);      
}

   // some model handler...
function fetchFunction(key) {
  console.log('call fetchFunction');
  return Promise.resolve(key + '_value');
}

   // modify callback...
   // example: model.fetchFunction =  memoized(new Map(), model.fetchFunction).bind(model);
fetchFunction = memoized(new Map(), fetchFunction);

// test...
(async () => {
  console.log(await fetchFunction('test'));
  console.log(await fetchFunction('test'));
})()
```